# How to re-use/substitute a variable in app.yaml file using App Engine on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I want to define "my_instance_name" once and re-use it in my app.yaml and index.php

My initial thought was to create an env_variable, but could not find a way to use it:
env_variables:
CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_MAIN: "my_instance_name"
beta_settings:
cloud_sql_instances: ?CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_MAIN?

Then I looked up how to define and reuse variables in yaml files via define:
define: &background_color '#998088'
fill-color: *background_color

But when I deployed my app,  I got a parsing error that said
'Anchors not supported in this handler'

Not sure what the right way to approach this is.

Here's an example of the app.yaml I tried:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: .

# dsd want to be able to create an env_var for this because
#   this instance name is used here and in index.php
#env_variables:
#  CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_MAIN: "my_unique_id:us-central1:main-instance"

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "my_unique_id:us-central1:main-instance"
```

Comment: You have to update (or build) your app.yaml file each time that you want to change the env vars.

Comment: Yeah, I get that part. I'm talking about re-use within a single build.

Comment: can you share your `yaml` file where you are reusing variables?

Comment: just updated the question with the sample of the code. still getting used to stack overflow. spent ten minutes trying to figure out how to post code with proper formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `app.yaml` as below:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: .

env_variables:
  CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_MAIN: &Instance_main
    "my_unique_id:us-central1:main-instance"

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: *Instance_main
```

Reference: [Introducing YAML anchors](https://mobile.blog/2021/09/09/clean-config-files-with-yaml-anchors/#:%7E:text=Anchors%20are%20a%20built%2Din,that%20node%20at%20that%20position.)

Comment: When I deploy to GCP I get 'Anchors not supported in this handler'.
It's referring to the '&Instance_main'.  I'm guessing the app.yaml 'interpreter' on GCP just doesn't support them.